# How to upload multiple images pressing ctrl key uploader using imacro?

Tags: imacros

I am using imacros with mozilla. I am trying to upload images to a website which uses file uploader like pressing ctrl key and select all images from a folder and uploader. I am unable to record this event by imacro.

Comment: What research have you done so far, what have you tried that hasn't worked?

Comment: [This information](http://wiki.imacros.net/Demo-Upload) may be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanx Benner!

Shugar! I already know basic imacros file uploading. I am very surprised that imacros team has not worked on this yet, most of the websites are using this type of file uploaders